# how to fix: Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server for app on the same machine?

Tags: sql-server, named-pipes

Please how can we resolve this error for apps accessing SQL server on the same machine?

I have run through ALL the the usual suggestions both on SO and Google.. no luck.

Windows 2016 server.
SQL Server 2017

This started after running the June windows updates.

**(EDIT) - Steps Taken:**

1) restarted the server --- OK

2) ensure MSSQLSERVER service is running --- OK

3) ensure I can access the sql server remotely from my laptop --- OK

4) remote into the server and try to start hMailServer Administrator --- ERROR

[image]

Comment: What suggestion(s) did you actually follow? If you really tried them *all* you would have solved the problem.

Comment: @Larnu the usual list:

Ensure TCP and named-pipes are enabled
Ensure the firewall is not blocking required ports (even on same machine)

Comment: Is the SQL Server Service running on the machine in question. How have you verified this?

Comment: @betelgeuce yes sir, i have even connected from my laptop to the sql server in question

Comment: Again.... please edit out the question and list out the things you tried. Including the tidbits in the comments here. Did the telnet test work? How about a UDL test? Does the sql server log indicate that it's listening on a port?

Comment: Also... that msgbox is a "hMailServer Administrator" message. What happens if you try to connect from SSMS?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid SSMS connects fine on the server both . and localhost

Comment: You say SSMS connects fine but hMailServer does not?

Comment: some one from the hmailserver forum just said to run Run "DBSetup"....... nd it all started working again.. very strange indeed. let me restart the server and see if the problem comes again

Comment: How does hmailserver know which server it should connect to? Do you type it in? I'm guessing it installs it's own server.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it has its own local hmailserver.ini

Comment: and that has a SQL server name and port etc. in it?

Comment: restarted and it all works fine. i feel this might have been an hmail server issue ... but  really strange , or transient one

Comment: If you could connect from SSMS and not hMail then it was definitely a hMail server issue